# Postgresql: How to use Substring with Regex?

Tags: regex, postgresql, case

I want to use a substring in a `CASE` statement that if it returns `true` then it will return whatever is in the `THEN` clause, such as:

```
CASE
WHEN substring(name, '\d\s\d{8}') THEN 'Long Name'
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need a boolean result, use a simple regular expression instead of the function `substring()`:

```
CASE WHEN name ~ '\d\s\d{8}' THEN 'Long Name' END
```

You can use the same regex pattern. Defaults to `NULL` if the pattern is not found.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the substring() you then need to evaluate the string that is returned by the substring function:

```
case
   when substring('foobar' from '\d\s\d{8}') IS NOT NULL then 'Long Name'
   else 'Short Name'
end
```